# Getting error parsing date string in Russian language in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert date string to date object in python 3 as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale

date_string = "Добавлено: суббота, 26 декабря 2015 г. в 11:01:59"
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "rus")
ru_date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string , 'Добавлено: %A, %d %B %Y г. в %H:%M:%S')
print(ru_date_object)
```

I get following error while executing the above code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:\Users***\Desktop\DateParser\20 nov.py", line 54, in 
>       ruDate = datetime.strptime(dateStr6, '\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e: %A, %d %B %Y \u0433. \u0432 %H:%M:%S')
>     File "F:\Users***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
>       tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
>     File "F:\Users***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
>       (data_string, format))
>   ValueError: time data '\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e: \u0441\u0443\u0431\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430, 26 \u0434\u0435\u043a\u0430\u0431\u0440\u044f 2015 \u0433. \u0432 11:01:59' does not match format '\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e: %A, %d %B %Y \u0433. \u0432 %H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in word 'декабря' which is not nominative. To parse this string into date you should to replace 'декабря' to 'декабрь'. You can do it this way:

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale

date_string = "Добавлено: суббота, 26 декабря 2015 г. в 11:01:59"
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "rus")
d = {'января': 'январь', 'декабря': 'декабрь'}
for k, v in d.items():
    date_string = date_string.replace(k, v)
ru_date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string , 'Добавлено: %A, %d %B %Y г. в %H:%M:%S')
print(ru_date_object)
```